# Regular Expression to Match and Split My Text C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have a text with specific pattern and I want to split it with that pattern using a regular expression in C#.

My pattern is `| <Date(MM/DD/YYYY or M/D/YYYY)> <Text(Comment)>`

In my text, I have comments separated with Pipe sign and date. I want to split this text where it starts with pipe and date.

Now the challenge I have there may be pipe sign in the comment. I want to ignore that an consider it as a full comment. Split text only it starts with pipe and date.

Another thing is the first date not start with pipe. Currently, I am separating text with pipe and then match with regular expression that it starts with date

Here I am giving some sample text

> 7/27/2017 Rec;'d 1 Juvederm Plus @ $550 (used $20 BD credit) total -
>   $530 (V) KK | 7/25/2017 sw to confirm. sl | 7/18/2017 sw - I called
>   her, as I wanted to get her in on 7/27. She is coming in at 2:45 for
>   numbing cream and then Kris will inject her at 3:30pm. Diane |
>   7/17/2017 connie needed to change her appt. from the 27th to the 10th.
>   She may come a few minutes early to numb up like usual. I told her if
>   anything she can numb up while in the waiting room. KM | 1/12/2017
>   Connie was tx'd with Dr. Numb and ice pre-tx. Kris injected her w/ Juv
>   ultra and noted: "0 remaining. 1st time tx'ing glabella. + results.
>   Will return in July for face and possible hands (Radiesse). | | $575
>   (juv ultra-$100) - $20 BD coupon - $50 (deposit) = $505 pd w/ visa. |
>   | I issued BD points and updated esales AM
>
> 6/29/2014 Thanks Elizabeth, I cannot afford those prices without the
>   groupon, as I have been unemployed for over one year. If prices go
>   down, or groupon offered, please let me know. | Maggie | | 6/26/2014
>   We checked your paperwork and you had 3 treatments for your lip and 3
>   treatments for your chin both done on groupon. We do not do groupons
>   anymore so the current pricing for those areas are as follows | | Lip
>   | Single treatment - 99 | 3 treat - 187.50 | 6 treat - 375 | 9 treat -
>   450 | | Chin | Single Treatment -101 | 3 treat - 201 | 6 treat - 402 |
>   9 treat - 482 | | I hope this was helpful | | 6/25/2014 Margaret lm on
>   rc - she did not say why she was calling - lm for her that she was in
>   our system and that it looked like she came for a groupon on the lip
>   or chin, which we dont offer anymoer, but if she would like to call on
>   Thursday we would pull her paperwork in Allentown -eliz | 8/28/2012
>   sw-eliz | 7/11/2012 She said that she lm 7/9 and sent email to cancel
>   but did not hear back, I canceled 7/11 for her 7/13 appt. no fee-mb

Comment: What about dates inside comments, are there any scenario like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This also seems to work atleast for your case:

```
(\|)*[\s]*\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}
```

Try it here:
https://regex101.com/r/MChVzn/1

Comment: Thanks, bro you make my work very easy. I changed it little bit (\|)*[\s?]*\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4} if there may be no space between pipe and date then also will work. I also changed date regex with mine and it working perfectly.

Comment: No need for ?. as * is for 0 or more occurences so that should work for no space also. By adding ? inside the [], now it will also check for ? (not a issue as it is in an OR condition) but is not required at all

Answer (score 1):

Something like this may do the trick:

```
(?:^| \| )\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}
```

You can play with it here: http://regexr.com/3h1tr

Note that you would need to run this on the two blocks you provided individually to get it to match the first "pipeless" date correctly on the second try, as ^ is used to match the beginning of the text.

Comment: Dimse your regex is also working but I mohit's regex working more properly for me.